# Filter the blank lines from DbgView output

Tags: windows, debugging

Is there some way to filter the blank lines from the displayed output in DbgView?
- apart from excluding a specific PID

Comment: Why not write your own OutputDebugString() viewer?  It's fairly straightforward to implement and you could add whatever filters you wanted.

Comment: Because (1) I'm not a hard code system internals programmer, and (2) I'd rather use off-the-shelf tools so I don't have another thing I've got to maintain, but thanks for the suggestion ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you can live without them , uncheck the menu item Options \ Win32 PIDs and then don't get the spurious blank lines

Comment: What do you mean 'if you can live without them'...thinking I can, but not sure what unchecking this option really means.  In 100% (or at least 99%) of the time, I just want to see the trace output from my own applications/websites Trace.WriteLine.  What is the 'real' affect of unchecking this option?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't get the PID for each process, so you cannot be sure which process the debug is coming

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a tool (free, open source) that has an option to remove empty lines. It's not 100% equivalent to DbgView but it has some other nice features (like the ability to colorize traces) :-).

It's available here: [TraceSpy](http://tracespy.codeplex.com/)

Comment: nice tool. process name resolution is a wonderful feature. capture animation is a bit annoying though.

Comment: @ishmaeel - do you mean the flickering that occurs when refreshing? this is due to the coloring capabilities.

Comment: I mean the animated gif in the menu, visible while capturing. It becomes a bit distracting. I would prefer a static, toggling image like the one in the Debugview toolbar.

Comment: @ishmaeel - ok I see. I'll make it optional for next version :-)

Answer (score -1):

You can set the Exclude Filter in DbgView to "]  " without the " characters. This does filter out the process id end delimiter character which does have the form

- ..[dddd]  Actual Content...

As long as you do not have too much output which does contain ] followed by two spaces it will filter out all empty lines.

Yours,
  Alois Kraus

Comment: Tried "] ", "] ", "]  *;"  ... all without " character, but none worked. However your suggestion did get me thinking and I spotted the Options \ Win32PIDs menu item. Unchecked that and the blank lines disappeared  !