# Why Does .net 4.0 Write All this Stuff to DebugView?

Tags: .net-4.0

When I run my .net 4.0 winforms application, I see tons of output in debugview (the following is an excerpt).  I routinely use debugview for debug messages so all this extra stuff can get quite noisy.

```
[8092] *** HR propagated: -2147024774
[8092] ***   Source File: d:\iso_whid\x86fre\base\isolation\com\enumidentityattribute.cpp, line 144
[8092] 
[8092] 
[8092] *** HR originated: -2147024774
[8092] ***   Source File: d:\iso_whid\x86fre\base\isolation\com\copyout.cpp, line 1302
[8092] 
[8092] 
[8092] *** HR propagated: -2147024774
[8092] ***   Source File: d:\iso_whid\x86fre\base\isolation\com\enumidentityattribute.cpp, line 144
[8092] 
[8092] 
[8092] *** HR originated: -2147024774
[8092] ***   Source File: d:\iso_whid\x86fre\base\isolation\com\copyout.cpp, line 1302
```

Does anyone know why this happens, and if/how I can prevent it?

Comment: Even worse, these are real problems ... they are "Unknow error" COM exceptions being raised.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I searched forever online before posting this question, but of course I find something as soon as I ask it.

This is a bug already reported here:
http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/535084/vs2010-debug-output-should-be-cleaned-up

Apparently, there are many aspects to this verbose debug output so it will take some time (next .net release) to get all the fixes released.

[VS 2010 SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=75568aa6-8107-475d-948a-ef22627e57a5&displaylang=en) is available now.

Comment: This thread still doesn't provide a fulfilling answer.  (and it's still a problem)  HR propagated/HR originated seems like something from just one team/toolset doesn't it?  Where did it come from?  

9/10'ths of these are COM error: 0x8007007A - 'The data area passed to a system call is too small.' 
from the same couple lines of code in two different source files.  Analysis please?

Comment: suspicious: what HIDs (human interface devices) need to be enumerated like this and what exactly is being isolated and what is copied..., and BTW it's still happening on windows 10 and VS 2019, maybe it's some mode windows enters when a debugger is running?  does it even have anything to do with VS?  Why is such legacy crap still being used?

Answer (score 7):

Workaround is to add some Exclude filters, but doesn't exclude blank lines:

> *originated*;*iso_whid*;*propagated*; ;

Comment: If one can exclude Win32 PIDs, one can also filter out blank lines. Throwing out dirty water sometimes requires foregoing the baby too. Such is the Zen of yin and yang. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4518918/filter-the-blank-lines-from-dbgview-output

Answer (score 2):

This has not been totally fixed in VS SP1, afaik. I have started a light alternative DebugView  community project here that can strip empty lines: http://tracespy.codeplex.com/ and also filter out those pesky "*** HR" traces...